# Is it possible to avoid heads-up notification of incoming calls?

Tags: android, android-immersive, heads-up-notifications

This is a very short question:

Suppose I have an immersive-screen Activity in the app, and I wish to give the users a choice of seeing heads-up notifications of incoming calls, because such a thing could cause accidental touches on the notifications (causing accidental replying or rejecting of calls), or because it's just annoying.

Is such a thing possible?

Even as a user, I've noticed that it's possible only if I enable do-not-disturb mode, and even then, I need to customize it so that it will be applied to such notifications.

Maybe there is a way to temporary enable do-not-disturb (as shown [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31862753/878126)), within the app? Or is there a better, alternative way ?

Comment: This answer could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22411581/mute-or-disable-phone-calls-while-app-is-running?rq=1

Comment: @Prexx How could it help? It doesn't have an answer, and it's not exactly the same... I explained the problem, but I'm not asking for do-not-disturb, unless this is the only solution, but even this isn't answered there...